# Colorbox works fine in chrome device emulator but not on physical iPhone

Tags: jquery, responsive, colorbox

I'm having an issue with the Colorbox jQuery plugin. My code runs fine on my Windows desktop. It is responsive and works fine on all device types using Chrome's device toolbar in the Developer Tools. When I run the exact same code on a physical iPhone (using Chrome or Safari) Colorbox opens but is not responsive.  I can see a brief flash almost like it is working but when it's done the content is not responsive and so requires left right scrolling.

Update: It appears to work just fine on an Android device.

The jQuery code is super simple (again it works fine on my desktop).

```
/* Initialize jQuery Colorbox*/
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.bookFrame', function() {
        $("a.bookFrame").colorbox({
            iframe: true,
            width: "800px",
            maxWidth: "80%",
            height: "80%",
        });
    });
});
```

Code is running live with some sample data (click on Canada then click on any book cover):  https://wanderreader.com/book-list/#

I'm not even sure where to start to figure this out.  Any tips for how I might debug this?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: One thing that occurred to me is that the content loading into the Colorbox iframe also contains an iframe itself so maybe when the iframe loads it's too wide and is triggering the parent iframe to resize.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely the iframe throwing the page off. It's set to 100% but is sizing wider than the screen width on an iphone.  It sizes itself just fine on android. Here's a page where you can see that is sizes fine on Chrome iphone emulator but doesn't on a physical iphone: https://wanderreader.com/griffintown-post/